# display select query data but i want create new table with subquery select it's fine but problem is that query run take time 30 minutes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, laravel

I want to optimize this query

Following query is working fine when I am using primary id in join condition

```
CREATE TABLE ssd
SELECT (
  SELECT SUM(litres) FROM `atg_old` as s_atg 
  WHERE s_atg.id=f_atg.id 
) as total FROM `atg_old` as f_atg
```

but when I am using another column, query takes way too long (30 min) 
eg.

```
CREATE TABLE ssd
SELECT (
  SELECT SUM(litres) FROM `atg_old`as s_atg WHERE 
  s_atg.vehicle_id=f_atg.vehicle_id
) as total FROM `atg_old` as f_atg
```

This is complete query

```
create table newtable
 Select start_date, CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) current_odo, 
CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) - ifnull((Select odo_meter from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id order by custtrans.start_date asc limit 1),CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED)) KmTraveled,
custmain.total_cost current_cost,
custmain.litres current_litre,
(Select sum(total_cost) from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id) `total_cost`,
(Select sum(litres) from customer_transactions_dashboard custtrans where custmain.start_date > custtrans.start_date
and CAST(odo_meter AS UNSIGNED) > 0 and custmain.site_id = custtrans.site_id and
custmain.vehicle_id = custtrans.vehicle_id) `total_liter`,
custmain.site_id, custmain.vehicle_id
from customer_transactions_dashboard custmain;
```

please reply

Comment: It looks like your query got cut off at the end. Either way, if you're adding another column into your where clause and it's taking a lot more time to run, then try indexing that column.

Comment: table is created but around 30 minutes after

Comment: I'm a bit confused, why not just use a `GROUP BY`? Are there additional conditions on your main query you're not showing?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you just want to store sum(litres) in a separate table, that too multiple times per vehicle id ?

You probably need something like following (or may be with a second column vehicle_id)

```
create table ssd  
select total from (
select sum(s.litres) total, s.vehicle_id from atg_old s 
group by s.vehicle_id ) a
```

Comment: but i am used multiple column and where condition

Comment: @Dharmendrasaini please edit your question to include your full query and table schema.